# Issues Installing Python Modules Under Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, easy-install

I am trying to setup a Python development environment in `Visual Studio 2013` using the new [`PTVS`](http://pytools.codeplex.com/). However, I need to be able to develop in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3. Here's what I have done so far for both versions:

1. Installed [`distribute`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute)
2. Installed [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)
3. Added `C:\Python 3.3\Scripts` & `C:\Python 2.7\Scripts` to my Path environment variable.

So in the Scripts folders I have:

- easy_install.exe
- easy_install-3.3.exe
- pip.exe
- pip-3.3.exe
- easy_install.exe
- easy_install-2.7.exe
- pip.exe
- pip-2.7.exe

Along with the executables  are the corresponding python scripts.

Now having done this, I am trying to install a Python module [`RPi.GPIO`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO), but I am getting the following error message:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip-2.7 install RPi.GPIO==0.5.3a
Downloading/unpacking RPi.GPIO==0.5.3a
  Downloading RPi.GPIO-0.5.3a.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package RPi.GPIO

Installing collected packages: RPi.GPIO
  Running setup.py install for RPi.GPIO
    building 'RPi.GPIO' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Python 2.7\python.exe" -c "import set
uptools;__file__='c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_Jon\\RPi.GPIO\\setup.p
y';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install
 --record c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\pip-svl0a1-record\install-record.txt --single-
version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\RPi

copying RPi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\RPi

running build_ext

building 'RPi.GPIO' extension

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command "C:\Program Files\Python 2.7\python.exe" -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\use
rs\\jon\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_Jon\\RPi.GPIO\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__fi
le__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jon\ap
pdata\local\temp\pip-svl0a1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-manage
d failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jon\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Jon\RPi.GPIO
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Jon\pip\pip.log

C:\Windows\system32>
```

It's trying real hard, but it is failing somewhere, and I can't trace it back to the source. Likewise, I always get the `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` know matter what module I try to install. What would cause this?

I have tried removed one of the interpreters path from the environment variables, because I thought that the duplicate `easy_install.exe instances might be conflicting`. **Making this change didn't help**.

Should the install be nearly as simple as:

```
pip-2.7 install RPi.GPIO==0.5.3a
```

or

```
pip-3.3 install RPi.GPIO==0.5.3a
```

**UPDATE:** I just tried install RPi.GPIO by using the command:

```
pip-3.3 install RPi.GPIO
```

and it was successfully installed, but the version is way out of date. Hm..?

Comment: The are many question on SO about the "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" problem. I suggest you read some of them and associated answers.

Comment: @martineau I'll have to take a look into that, but that's not the main issue here.